# disable or block edit button in view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my index view, which shows the results from one table.

I would like to block the edit link or show some info dialog ("The option to edit locked."):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
```

Only when value of this row:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
```

Is equal to 1.

How can I achieve this?

**Index View:**

```
@model ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Instructors";
}

<h2>Instructors</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Is Active</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Instructors)
    {
        string selectedRow = "";
        if (item.ID == ViewBag.InstructorID)
        {
            selectedRow = "success";
        }
        <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, if you want to hide link completely use:

```
 @if (item.IsActive == 1)
 {
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
 }
```

Or if you want to replace it with text:

```
@if (item.IsActive == 1) 
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
}
else
{
    <span>The option to edit locked.</span>
}
```